# CUDA: How to reuse kernels in multiple files (for unit testing)

Tags: linker, cuda

How can I go about reusing the same kernel without getting fatal linker errors due to defining the symbol multiple times?

In Visual Studio I get:

```
"fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found"
```

I have three files: `Interface.h`, `Kernel.cu`, and `Wrapper.cu`. My current structure is as follows (ala the ["C++ integration" SDK example](http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-cc-sdk-code-samples)):

```
//Interface.h 
extern "C" void myCfunction( ... );

//Kernel.cu
__global__ void my_kernel( ... );

//Wrapper.cu
#include "Interface.h"
#include "Kernel.cu"

extern "C" void myCfunction( ... );

void myCfunction( ... ) {
    // Call CUDA kernel in Kernel.cu
    my_kernel<<< ... >>>( ... );
}
```

This all works fine.

But if I add another C function in another file which also includes `Kernel.cu` and uses those kernels, I get the above error. e.g.

```
//NewWrapper.cu
#include "Kernel.cu"

extern "C" void myNewCfunction( ... );

void myNewCfunction( ... ) {
    // Call CUDA kernel in Kernel.cu
    my_kernel<<< ... >>>( ... );
    // Now I get linker errors...
}
```

So how can I reuse the kernels in `Kernel.cu` among many C functions in different files.

The purpose of this by the way is unit testing, and integrating my kernels with CPP unit, if there is no way to reuse kernels (there must be!) then other suggestions for unit testing kernels within my existing CPP unit framework would be appreciate.

Comment: I'm finding this a bit hard to follow -- when you say "C function", what you really mean is "C-interface function in a .cu file that calls CUDA kernels", yes?  As opposed to "purely-C function in a .c file"?  (And `Wrapper.cu` defines `myCfunction()`?)

Comment: Also, as an aside, this is one of the reasons I think it's useful to distinguish `.cu` and `.cuh` files; if you're not compiling `Kernel.cu` directly and instead including it in other `.cu` files, it should have a `.cuh` extension to make that clear.

Comment: Sorry, it is a little convoluted.  Interface.h just contains the external interface to a C function myCfunction() which is defined in Wrapper.cu and itself calls the kernels defined in kernel.cu.  The problem is I want to create another different C function to call my kernels defined in kernel.cu, say myNewCfunction() defined in a file other than wrapper.cu.  The real goal is to create a unit testing code, in which I can include kernels defined in various places and test them independently of the C interfaces that call them in normal operation.

Answer (score 5):

Create launcher functions and reference them from a header which will be included from multiple locations.

In .cu file:

```
__global__ myKernel(){...}

void myKernelLauncher(){ myKernel<<<...>>>()...}
```

In .h file

```
void myKernelLauncher();
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution that usually works for me is to compile a library out of all the cu files and
create entry points to initialize the kernel.

Otherwise put all the common functions inside a .cuh and wrap it if #IFDEF _MYHEADER_H